# React Native align-items: baseline not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to align 2 svg icons and a view with some text to the baseline, but as you can see from the snapshot it's not working.
[image]

This is the result that I want:
[image]

This is the code:

```
<View style={styles.header}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} style={{marginRight: 20}}>
          <MenuIcon />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.date}>24 ottobre 2019</Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Compiti</Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate({routeName: 'Calendary'})} style={{position: 'absolute', right:0}}>
          <CalendarIcon width={50} height={50} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

and this is the style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'baseline',
  },
  date: {
    color: '#C8C8C8',
    fontSize: 15
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#454545',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `header` style should be as following :

```
header: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center', // add center instead of flex-end
}
```

Comment: I want it to be at baseline, not center